# Custom navigation menu bar

Tags: routes, navigation

I use the main menu as navigation bar, and I would like to obtain the following result: When the mouse is hovered on one navigation item, the sub menu should be shown as `<div>` under this item. I would like to be able to style the sub menu `<div>`s as well.

Shall I actually use the navigation menu or just the main menu?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: details r not enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are looking for something like [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) or [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).

My personal preference is Superfish, as it has become pretty damn useful in recent updates. It's also responsive if that's a requirement, and support touchscreens quite nicely.

**EDIT**

Something I missed (possibly another personal preference) is that I find the CSS for Nice Menus an absolute NIGHTMARE in comparison with Superfish.

Comment: Didn't know Superfish was responsive now, awesome :)

Comment: Yup - surprised me too when I was doing a responsive site and it just worked ;-)

Comment: I've used Nice Menu like forever. I agree that initially figuring out the CSS is confusing. Use an override file to change just the things you need. I also agree that the latest (dev version important!) of Superfish is very convenient; yeah, it just works! Many options for screen or user agent.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on your theme. It is often useful to turn off the main menu in the theme appearance settings, and then using the block system to place the menu.

NiceMenus or Superfish give you the ability to modify the drop-downs. With NiceMenus you'll have to set the @media breakpoints yourself for different screen sizes. Superfish has these features built-in, which can save you a lot of responsive design-time.

Also, see the Menu Block module which has lots of menu placement options.